# Regex lines with exactly 4 semicolons

Tags: r, regex

I want to filter lines with exactly 4 semicolons in it.

More or less semicolons should not be processed. I'm using regex/grep:

POSITIVE Example:

```
VES_I.MG;A;97;13;1
```

NEGATIVE Example:

```
VES_I.MG;A;97;13;1;2
```

Comment: @fedorqui, cool. NP. Hopefully our comments are a good tutorial for the  OP :-)

Answer (score 3):

For something this straightforward, I would actually just suggest counting the semicolons and subsetting based on that numeric vector.

A fast way to do this is with `stri_count*` from the "stringi" package:

```
library(stringi)
v <- c("VES_I.MG;A;97;13;1", "VES_I.MG;A;97;13;1;2")  ## An example vector
stri_count_fixed(v, ";")                         ## How many semicolons?
# [1] 4 5
v[stri_count_fixed(v, ";") == 4]                 ## Just keep when count == 4
# [1] "VES_I.MG;A;97;13;1"
```

Answer (score 2):

**[EDIT: Fixed stupid bug...]**

The following will work with `grep` or any regex engine:

```
^[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*$
```

When used in a command line, make sure you put it inside quotes (`"` on Windows; either kind on *nix) so that special characters aren't interpreted by the shell.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?=([^;]*;){4}[^;]*$).*$
```

You can try this with `grep -P` if you have the support for it.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/22

Comment: No, I'm using the R programming language

Comment: @Impulsleistung `R` supprts lookaheads.Use `perl=True` option.

Comment: You did it, this works: grepl(pattern = "^(?=([^;]*;){4}[^;]*$).*$",x = raw_data,perl = TRUE)

Answer (score 2):

If you have `awk` available, you can also try:

```
awk -F';' 'NF==5' file
```

just replace the `5` with `n + 1`. which `n` is  your target count, for example the `4` in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use lookaheads and also you don't need to enable `perl=TRUE` parameter.

```
> v <- c("VES_I.MG;A;97;13;1", "VES_I.MG;A;97;13;1;2")
> grep("^(?:[^;]*;){4}[^;]*$", v)
[1] 1
> grep("^(?:[^;]*;){4}[^;]*$", v, value=TRUE)
[1] "VES_I.MG;A;97;13;1"
```

Answer (score 0):

To match exactly four semicolons in a line, grep using the regex `^([^;]*;){4}[^;]*$`:

```
grep -P "^([^;]*;){4}[^;]*$" ./input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done without regular expressions by using `count.fields`.  The first line gives the counts and the second line reads in the lines and reduces it to those lines with 5 fields.  The final line parses the fields out and converts it to a data frame with 4 columns.

```
 cnt <- count.fields("myfile.dat", sep = ";")
 L <- readLines("myfile.dat")[cnt == 5]

 read.table(text = L, sep = ";")
```